# What traits should a devotee have in order to meet the divine?

Tags: scripture, gods, goddess, bhakti, prayer

Per scripture, what traits should a devotee have in order to meet the divine?

How should a real devotee be? What are the traits needed for a devotee to make his worshipped deity appear before him?

Comment: Do what the deity has told you to do and do not do what the deity has told you to not to do.

Comment: I think even having some traits will not qualify for darshan, unless god wishes